# check if object is defined in jquery to avoid errors

Tags: jquery

In case that there is an objects called (id) "ABC123", I want to scroll down automatic to that object. That works fine if this object exist. But if not, I receive an error:
**"TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined"**

My code should avoid this error, but doesn't work:

```
if(typeof($('#ABC123')) != 'undefined') {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($("#ABC123").offset().top-100) }, 0).scroll();
    }
```

Comment: make sure you mark the correct answer with a green check mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery collection is never `undefined`.

Simply test that it's not empty :

```
if ($('#ABC123').length) {
```

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery object will never be `null` or `undefined`, even you're not passing any argument `$()`, In this case it's just empty and simply do nothing.

Seem like you want to check whether it's empty or not:

```
if ($('#ABC123').length) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($("#ABC123").offset().top-100) }, 0).scroll();
});
```